# Replace substring inside a text file starting from character and ending with another character

Tags: string, batch-file

I'm newbie using batch scripting, and i've this problem :
I try to substitute a particular string inside a file, starting with a char specific `@` and ending with `,`

This is my code, that simply extract a set of data from a csv:

```bat
@echo off
D:
cd TEST 
(for /f "tokens=6,13,14 delims=|" %%a in (11_02_19_09.csv) do %%a,%%b,%c) > FROM_IMPORT.csv 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set in=FROM_IMPORT.csv 
set out=TO_IMPORT.csv 
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %in%') do ( set line=%%a >>%out% echo !line: =! )
```

The output is a set of lines like this `RMT,15018@10.71,TEST` what i search to do, is removing string starting from `@` and ending with `,`

Example : If had someting like this `RMT,15018@10.71,TEST` i want to get something like this : `RMT,15018,TEST`

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how?

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please share a [mcve] of your coding attempts! Note that this is not a tutorial site but a place to ask programming-specific questions. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and learn [ask] here!

Comment: Thanks, this is my code, that simply extract a set of data from a csv: D:
cd TEST
(for /f "tokens=6,13,14 delims=|" %%a in (11_02_19_09.csv) do %%a,%%b,%c) > FROM_IMPORT.csv
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set in=FROM_IMPORT.csv
set out=TO_IMPORT.csv
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('type %in%') do (
   set line=%%a
   >>%out% echo !line: =!
)               the output is a set of lines like this       RMT,15018@10.71,TEST what i search to do, is removing string starting from @ and ending with, . I hope this can help, thanks in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your question to post code, do not commenting for that!

Comment: Did you mean if you had something like this `RMT,15018@10.71,TEST` You want to get as result `RMT,15018,TEST`

Comment: Thanks Hackoo, it's exactly what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try with this code that use regex in vbscript to search a pattern and replace it. [Demo Here](https://regex101.com/r/WKld4H/1)

```bat
@echo off
Title Replace String using Regex with vbscript
Set "InputFile=in.csv"
Set "OutPutFile=out.csv"
Call :Search_Replace "%InputFile%" "%OutPutFile%"
Start /MAX Notepad "%OutputFile%" & Exit
::-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Search_Replace <InputFile> <OutPutFile>
(
    echo WScript.StdOut.WriteLine Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Function Search_Replace(Data^)
    echo Dim strPattern, strReplace, strResult,oRegExp
    echo Data = "%~1" 
    echo Data = WScript.StdIn.ReadAll
    echo strPattern = "\b@\S+?,\b"
    echo strReplace = ","
    echo Set oRegExp = New RegExp
    echo oRegExp.Global = True 
    echo oRegExp.IgnoreCase = True 
    echo oRegExp.Pattern = strPattern
    echo strResult = oRegExp.Replace(Data,strReplace^)
    echo Search_Replace = strResult
    echo End Function
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
cscript //nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" < "%~1" > "%~2"
If Exist "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" Del "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
Exit /B
::----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```